# EdgeRouter Policy Based Routing not working for second LAN

Tags: policy-routing, ubiquiti-edgerouter

I have an EdgeRouter ER-8 with the following setup: 3 WANs (eth0 is ISP1, eth1 is ISP2, eth2 is a wireless link to another campus with its own ISP, and it is used to access the remote LAN and as a third and failover-only uplink); and 2 local LANs (eth6-192.168.1.1/24; eth7-172.18.16.1/22).

The LAN on eth6 was just added. An independent legacy router failed and we decided to integrate that LAN to the core services. Load-balance is configured and functioning as expected, for clients on boths LANs. PBR is configured, but apparently it is only working for clients on eth7, and not for clients on the second LAN, on eth6.

I created a couple of address groups, so as to force IPs listed on the first one, to always use ISP1/eth0, and those listed on the second one, to use ISP2/eth1.

If I add IPs from the 172.18.16.0/22 network to the lists, everything works as it should. If I add IPs from the 192.168.1.0/24 network those clients keep falling back to the default behavior (lb-group G).

Rules 95 and 96 of the firewall do the mangling, but by monitoring the statistics (`show firewall modify statistics`) I realized that requests from IPs (in the address groups) from the 172... network do hit those rules, BUT requests from IPs (again, in the exact same address groups) from the 192... network do not.

I verified this also by executing `watch -n 1 'curl api.ipify.org'` on clients on both networks. Those on the 172... network show the IP of the corresponding ISP, while those on the other network show alternating IPs (meaning, they are indeed following the load-balance parameters).

What I'm I missing? There must be something I'm not seeing or not applying to the eth6 interface.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my configuration:

```
firewall {
     all-ping enable
     broadcast-ping disable
     group {
         address-group OUT-WAN-ETH0 {
             address 192.168.1.251
             description "Out through eth0"
         }
         address-group OUT-WAN-ETH1 {
             address 192.168.1.252
             description "Out through eth1"
         }
         network-group Old_LAN {
             description "Legacy networks"
             network 192.168.1.0/24
         }
         network-group PRIVATE_NETS {
             network 172.18.16.0/22
             network 172.18.20.0/22
             network 172.18.24.0/29
             network 172.18.24.8/29
             network 172.18.24.16/29
             network 192.168.1.0/24
         }
         port-group servicios_proxy {
             port 80
             port 443
             port 873
             port 11194
             port 22
         }
     }
     ipv6-receive-redirects disable
     ipv6-src-route disable
     ip-src-route disable
     log-martians disable
     modify balance {
         rule 10 {
             action modify
             description "do NOT load balance lan to lan"
             destination {
                 group {
                     network-group PRIVATE_NETS
                 }
             }
             modify {
                 table main
             }
         }
         rule 20 {
             action modify
             description "do NOT load balance destination public address"
             destination {
                 group {
                     address-group ADDRv4_eth0
                 }
             }
             modify {
                 table main
             }
         }
         rule 30 {
             action modify
             description "do NOT load balance destination public address"
             destination {
                 group {
                     address-group ADDRv4_eth1
                 }
             }
             modify {
                 table main
             }
         }
         rule 40 {
             action modify
             description "do NOT load balance destination public address"
             destination {
                 group {
                     address-group ADDRv4_eth2
                 }
             }
             modify {
                 table main
             }
         }
         rule 95 {
             action modify
             description "Output through WAN-eth0"
             modify {
                 lb-group WAN-eth0
             }
             source {
                 group {
                     address-group OUT-WAN-ETH0
                 }
             }
         }
         rule 96 {
             action modify
             description "Output through WAN-eth1"
             modify {
                 lb-group WAN-eth1
             }
             source {
                 group {
                     address-group OUT-WAN-ETH1
                 }
             }
         }
         rule 110 {
             action modify
             modify {
                 lb-group G
             }
         }
     }
     name WAN_IN {
         default-action drop
         description "WAN to internal"
         enable-default-log
         rule 10 {
             action accept
             description "Allow established/related"
             state {
                 established enable
                 related enable
             }
         }
         rule 20 {
             action accept
             description v-proxy
             destination {
                 address 192.168.1.253
                 group {
                     port-group servicios_proxy
                 }
             }
             log disable
             protocol tcp_udp
         }
         rule 40 {
             action drop
             description "Drop invalid state"
             state {
                 invalid enable
             }
         }
     }
     name WAN_LOCAL {
         default-action drop
         description "WAN to router"
         enable-default-log
         rule 10 {
             action accept
             description "Allow established/related"
             state {
                 established enable
                 related enable
             }
         }
         rule 30 {
             action drop
             description "Drop invalid state"
             state {
                 invalid enable
             }
         }
     }
     name Wireless_backhaul {
         default-action drop
         description ""
         rule 10 {
             action accept
             description "Allow to Backhaul"
             destination {
                 address 0.0.0.0/0
             }
             log disable
             protocol all
             state {
                 established enable
                 invalid disable
                 new enable
                 related enable
             }
         }
         rule 20 {
             action drop
             description "Drop invalid state"
             log disable
             protocol all
             state {
                 established disable
                 invalid enable
                 new disable
                 related disable
             }
         }
     }
     receive-redirects disable
     send-redirects enable
     source-validation disable
     syn-cookies enable
 }
 interfaces {
     ethernet eth0 {
         address dhcp
         description WAN1
         dhcp-options {
             default-route update
             default-route-distance 3
             name-server no-update
         }
         duplex auto
         firewall {
             in {
                 name WAN_IN
             }
             local {
                 name WAN_LOCAL
             }
         }
         speed auto
     }
     ethernet eth1 {
         address dhcp
         description WAN2
         dhcp-options {
             default-route update
             default-route-distance 3
             name-server no-update
         }
         duplex auto
         firewall {
             in {
                 name WAN_IN
             }
             local {
                 name WAN_LOCAL
             }
         }
         speed auto
     }
     ethernet eth2 {
         address 172.18.24.1/29
         description Wireless-SB448-In
         duplex auto
         firewall {
             in {
                 name Wireless_backhaul
             }
             local {
                 name Wireless_backhaul
             }
             out {
                 name Wireless_backhaul
             }
         }
         speed auto
         vif 2 {
             address 172.18.24.10/29
             description Wireless-SB448-out
             firewall {
                 in {
                     name Wireless_backhaul
                 }
                 local {
                     name Wireless_backhaul
                 }
                 out {
                     name Wireless_backhaul
                 }
             }
         }
         vif 3 {
             address 172.18.24.18/29
             description Wireless-SB448-LAN
             firewall {
                 in {
                     name Wireless_backhaul
                 }
                 local {
                     name Wireless_backhaul
                 }
                 out {
                     name Wireless_backhaul
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     ethernet eth6 {
         address 192.168.1.1/24
         description LAN-old
         duplex auto
         firewall {
             in {
                 modify balance
             }
         }
         speed auto
     }
     ethernet eth7 {
         address 172.18.16.1/22
         description LAN
         duplex auto
         firewall {
             in {
                 modify balance
             }
         }
         speed auto
     }
     loopback lo {
     }
 }
 load-balance {
     group G {
         exclude-local-dns disable
         flush-on-active enable
         gateway-update-interval 1
         interface eth0 {
             route-test {
                 count {
                     failure 3
                     success 2
                 }
                 initial-delay 1
                 interval 2
                 type {
                     ping {
                         target 8.8.4.4
                     }
                 }
             }
             weight 100
         }
         interface eth1 {
             route-test {
                 count {
                     failure 3
                     success 2
                 }
                 initial-delay 1
                 interval 2
                 type {
                     ping {
                         target 8.8.8.8
                     }
                 }
             }
             weight 100
         }
         interface eth2.2 {
             failover-only
             route-test {
                 count {
                     failure 3
                     success 5
                 }
                 initial-delay 1
                 interval 2
                 type {
                     ping {
                         target 172.18.24.9
                     }
                 }
             }
             weight 1
         }
         lb-local enable
         lb-local-metric-change disable
         sticky {
             dest-addr enable
             source-addr enable
         }
     }
     group WAN-eth0 {
         exclude-local-dns enable
         flush-on-active enable
         gateway-update-interval 5
         interface eth0 {
             route-test {
                 initial-delay 1
                 interval 10
                 type {
                     ping {
                         target 8.8.8.8
                     }
                 }
             }
             weight 100
         }
         lb-local disable
         lb-local-metric-change disable
         sticky {
             dest-addr enable
             source-addr enable
         }
     }
     group WAN-eth1 {
         exclude-local-dns enable
         flush-on-active enable
         gateway-update-interval 5
         interface eth1 {
             route-test {
                 initial-delay 1
                 interval 10
                 type {
                     ping {
                         target 8.8.8.8
                     }
                 }
             }
             weight 100
         }
         lb-local disable
         lb-local-metric-change disable
         sticky {
             dest-addr enable
             source-addr enable
         }
     }
 }
 protocols {
     static {
         route 0.0.0.0/0 {
             next-hop 172.18.24.9 {
                 description "SB448"
                 distance 5
             }
             next-hop 192.168.2.254 {
                 description "ISP2"
                 distance 4
             }
         }
         route 172.18.20.0/22 {
             next-hop 172.18.24.17 {
                 description LAN-SB448
                 distance 2
             }
         }
     }
 }
services {... OMITTED ...}
system   {... OMITTED ...}
```